# Pullback o tirato-indietro?

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

Il [pullback di una forma](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-back) è definito in questo articolo di Wikipedia. Ora, io di solito lo chiamo pullback, ma il mio relatore mi ha detto di chiamarlo tirato-indietro. Però su wikipedia lo chiamano pullback, gli [appunti di Geometria 3](http://peano.matapp.unimib.it/~conti/note14.pdf) (corso tenuto da un altro professore nella mia università) lo chiamano pullback, l'esercitatrice del mio relatore pure lo chiamava pullback, il prof di Fisica 2 parla di «mappa pull-back», e in breve "tirato-indietro" sembra una parola di uso esclusivo del mio relatore. Quindi se pullback è veramente più "standard" di tirato-indietro, io non cambierei tutte le occorrenze di pullback nella mia tesi in tirato-indietro. Secondo voi è più "standard" chiamarlo pullback o tirato-indietro?

Comment: Che sia più “standard” chiamarlo pullback è poco ma sicuro. Io semmai mi chiederei se non ci possa essere qualche altro motivo per usare lo stesso un termine italiano (magari più orecchiabile di “tirato-indietro”).

Comment: Qualche suggerimento di alternativa?

Comment: Leggo su Wikipedia che il termine tedesco è _Rücktransport_ ("trasporto indietro"). Purtroppo non c'è l'articolo corrispondente in francese, che probabilmente avrebbe fornito un buon suggerimento per un termine italiano.

Comment: Per la cronaca, in Spagnolo è Aplicación regrediente, Applicazione regredente.

Comment: **Se** ha a che fare con il [pullback in teoria delle categorie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29) (cosa che è possibile, bisognerebbe vedere se la definizione categoriale coincide con quella sugli spazi vettoriali quando si definiscono in teoria delle categorie) lo potresti chiamare qualcosa come "prodotto fibrato". Comunque quello che farei e semplicemente andare a pescarmi degli articoli/libri in italiano che lo citino e "sbattere in faccia" al professore che *tirato-indietro* semplicemente non esiste nel lessico tecnico.

Comment: In spagnolo e anche in catalano, io ho usato "pullback", ma a volte ho ascoltato "aplicación recíproca" (in spagnolo). "Aplicación regrediente" non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: L'avrà inventato la Wiki spagnola :). In effetti la WIki Catalana dice pullback se ben ricordo.

Comment: In effetti leggendo [l'articolo in spagnolo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplicaci%C3%B3n_regrediente) si osserva che comincia dando l'alternativa, e poi usa solo pullback. Più usato su Wikipedia è _aplicación progrediente_ per il pushforward, anche se sono sempre in coppia e vengono usati tipo 2 volte in tutto l'articolo.

Comment: In effetti Googlando [tirato indietro geometria differenziale](https://www.google.it/search?q=tirato+indietro+geometria+differenziale&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NHIJVuH7IMqrsAHg0b7YAw) si ottengono solo risultati in cui si dice "tirare indietro" come motivazione del termine pullback, mai un participio passato.

Comment: Non credo c'entri col prodotto fibrato, qualunque cosa esso sia. Da quel che leggo si Wikipedia, è un'altra cosa.

Comment: @MickG Ho sempre e solo sentito (e detto) *pullback* (e *pushout* per il concetto duale). Termine specialistico: nessun problema. Se il tuo relatore pretende *tirato-indietro*, prova a obiettare che non lo usa nessuno e poi, a ordine perentorio, esegui. `;-)` Hai sempre LaTeX dalla tua parte: `\newcommand{\pb}{tirato-indietro}\newcommand{\pbs}{tirati-indietro}` da cambiare, per la tua edizione personale, in `\newcommand{\pb}{pullback}\newcommand{\pbs}{pullback}`

Comment: @egreg Ma [pushout](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)) non è il concetto duale del pullback o prodotto fibrato in teoria delle categorie? Io parlo di [pullback di forme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)), non di pullback in teoria delle categorie, quindi il duale sarebbe il pushforward...

Comment: @MickG Non cambia molto.

Comment: @egreg Davvero? A legger Wikipedia sembrano due cose completamente diverse. Comunque buon suggerimento, ma è tardi per applicarlo perché la parte in cui si usano i pullback l'ho già finita scrivendo pullback esplicitamente :(, quindi dovrei comunque cambiarli tutti in `\pb` e prima di farlo vorrei capire se serve e a quel punto cambio direttamente in tirato/i-indietro :). E poi userei un `\@ifstar` per il plurale, sicché non `\pbs` ma `\pb*` :).

Comment: Da notare [l'abbondanza di risultati con pullback](https://www.google.it/#q=pullback+geometria+differenziale) e [la totale assenza di risultati con tirato-indietro](https://www.google.it/#q=tirato-indietro+geometria+differenziale), se non casi con voci verbali distinte come "tirare indietro" o "viene tirata indietro".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nei cinque anni che ho passato in un università italiana (Pisa) non ho mai sentito "tirato indietro" se non come verbo informale (e.g. "Prendiamo questa forma, la tiriamo indietro sull'altra varietà e integriamo..") e onestamente mi fa un po' strano. Notare che nella mia specialità il pullback si usa parecchio per cui se fosse un uso comune probabilmente l'avrei sentito.

È interessante notare che per un concetto simile (il pullback di fasci) Grothendieck in francese usa "image réciproque", mentre Cartan chiama il pullback di forme "changement de variable" (e.g. nel suo libro "Formes différentielles"). Perciò se dovessi inventare un termine italiano io proporrei "immagine inversa" o "preimmagine" (secondo me "cambio di variabili" è meno comprensibile). In ogni caso si tratterebbe di una terminologia non standard.

Personalmente consiglio "pullback", poi è chiaro che nella stesura della tesi l'opinione del relatore è importante.

Incidentalmente il termine "pullback" in teoria delle categorie è un concetto completamente diverso, anche se sicuramente collegato, ed anche lì ho sentito solo "pullback" (anche se "pullback square" si può tradurre con "quadrato cartesiano").

Answer (score 2):

Secondo me, pullback è la forma corretta, da utilizzare anche in Italiano. Si tratta di uno di quei vocaboli "ereditati" dall'inglese, che non si possono tradurre senza una perdita di significato. Si può pensare a termini di altre branche scientifiche, come l'informatica: vocaboli come "account", "desktop", "server" non vengono tradotti! Inoltre, trattandosi di un operatore utilizzato in matematica, penso sia importante mantenere un "dizionario" comune a tutti i ricercatori, laddove traduzioni "improvvisate" potrebbero compromettere la formalità di eventuali trattazioni (come la tua tesi).

Io, fossi in te, cercherei di convincere il mio relatore a mantenere la forma originaria mostrandogli la pagina Wikipedia italiana per il vocabolo "Pull-back": https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-back : come vedi, il nome della voce resta in Inglese!

Comment: In questa argomentazione c'è del vero (anche se persino per molti termini tecnici esistono – o avrebbe senso coniare – equivalenti in italiano). Ma il consiglio di usare, per sostenere le proprie ragioni, una pagina della Wikipedia (e per giunta di quella italiana) rischia di essere controproducente: lo sarebbe per me e per più d'uno che conosco.

Comment: Come riferimento potrebbe essere utile il libro di Abate-Tovena "Geometria differenziale", disponibile su Springerlink (se l'università è abbonata).